# Dynamically add a class to specific portion of the span

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to dynamically add a class to a specific sentence of the defined span.

Let's say I want to add `focusColorClass` CSS class to this sentence of the span:

> How could you do this without telling me?!

How can we achieve this?

I have tried this with no luck!

```js
const selectSpan = document.getElementById('dialogue-span')
const sentence = "How could you do this without telling me?!";
selectSpan.innerHTML = selectSpan.innerHTML.replace(new RegExp('(' + sentence + ')'), `<span class="focusColorClass">${sentence}</span>`);
```

```css
.focusColorClass {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="answerSentence" class="answerSentence-class">

<span id="dialogue-span">You pirced her ears. How could you do this without telling me?! Now if I had told you Then it would'nt have been a surprise! now would it?! I think she looks cute... But I'm wrong!!!</span>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const selectSpan = document.getElementById('dialogue-span')
const sentence = "How could you do this without telling me?!";
selectSpan.innerHTML = selectSpan.innerHTML.replace(sentence, `<span class="focusColorClass">${sentence}</span>`);
```

```css
.focusColorClass {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="answerSentence" class="answerSentence-class">

<span id="dialogue-span">You pirced her ears. How could you do this without telling me?! Now if I had told you Then it would'nt have been a surprise! now would it?! I think she looks cute... But I'm wrong!!!</span>

</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `replace` function. This replaces the sentence you are looking for with your code.

```js
const selectSpan = document.getElementById('dialogue-span')
const sentence = "How could you do this without telling me?!";
selectSpan.innerHTML = selectSpan.innerText.replace(sentence, `<span class="focusColorClass">${sentence}</span>`);
```

```css
.focusColorClass {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="answerSentence" class="answerSentence-class">

<span id="dialogue-span">You pirced her ears. How could you do this without telling me?! Now if I had told you Then it would'nt have been a surprise! now would it?! I think she looks cute... But I'm wrong!!!</span>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the start and end index of the sentence in the content and add a `span` parent to this `substring` with the color class as follows:

```js
const selectSpan = document.getElementById('dialogue-span');
const sentence = "How could you do this without telling me?!";
let content = selectSpan.innerHTML;
let start = content.indexOf(sentence), end = start+sentence.length;
console.log(start,end);
if(start>-1)
     selectSpan.innerHTML = content.substring(0,start) + `<span class="focusColorClass">${sentence}</span>` + content.substring(end,content.length);
```

```css
.focusColorClass {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="answerSentence" class="answerSentence-class">

<span id="dialogue-span">You pirced her ears. How could you do this without telling me?! Now if I had told you Then it would'nt have been a surprise! now would it?! I think she looks cute... But I'm wrong!!!</span>

</div>
```